# ReadProcessMemory | ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY (12b)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
SIZE_T bytesRead;
    DWORDLONG DecimalBaseAddr = GetModuleBase (gameName, pID);
    cout << "The Base Address is: " << DecimalBaseAddr << "\n";  <----- Здесь значение 3868262400 
    vector<DWORD> pointsOffsets{ 0x1700, 0x0, 0x10, 0x8, 0x988 };
    DWORD WorldPtr = 0x258C9D0;
    DWORDLONG buff = (DecimalBaseAddr + WorldPtr);   <----- 0xe8e9c9d0
    DWORDLONG WorldAddr = NULL;




    if (ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)buff, &WorldAddr, sizeof(DWORDLONG), &bytesRead)) {
        cout << "World Pointer2 is: " << "0x" << hex << WorldAddr << "\n";
        cin.get();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Failed to read memory" << GetLastError() << endl;
        cout << "Bytes read: " << bytesRead << endl;
        cin.get();
    }
```

Функция ReadProcessMemory выдает ошибку 12b, с чем это может быть связано?
Ошибка: ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY

299 (0x12B)

Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.

Comment: Что такое ошибка 12b?

Comment: ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY

299 (0x12B)

Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.

Comment: Ха, так может привести текст и название ошибки в вопросе а не её номер 12B? :)  Предполагаю, что количество людей, помнящих коды ошибок во всех используемых API, крайне мало :)

Comment: Внес в топик расшифровку ошибки.

Comment: Посмотрите тут и похожие темы по этой ошибке https://stackoverflow.com/q/34648061/13970074

Comment: Проблема все еще открыта, я не могу прочитать указатель, чтобы смещаться дальше по памяти. :/